# Deriving from singleton : one object each of base and derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a `singleton class A`, with `virtual protected destructor` and `private constructor`. I derived publicly from it and create class B.

Can i create two objects one each of base and derived class ?

If i cannot is there any other way to share same code ?

When i tried it i am getting compile time errors :

```
warning C4356: 'A::variable' : static data member cannot be initialized 
via derived class

B.cpp(4): error C2371: 'variable' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: Theoretically you can, if the base class has a protected constructor.

Comment: Don’t use singletons and you won’t have problems related to singletons.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and find out?

Comment: Don't write software and you won't have problems related to software engineering. Sound logic. :P

Comment: @TonyTheLion Except that singletons are a rather problematic pattern (it's just a thinly veiled global variable, after all), so avoiding singletons generally leads to fewer problems and better design. I understand singleton utility when dealing with legacy code, but I try hard to avoid the (anti-)pattern in any new code I write.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975 (although that just describes language-independent conceptual problems; C++ adds a whole pile of lifetime-management issues to the mix).

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Sometimes we need to write software, so we have to deal with some problems. There's no need to create more problems than necessary when we do that.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your singleton is implemented.  If it has a public constructor of some sort than you're probably fine with extending it's singleton-ness to a derived instance of `B`.  If it's some kind of factory method then probably not.  The fact that it has a `protected dtor` is a sign that it was built for use as a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused with two independent idioms:

- Inheritance is a part of C++ language mechanics
- Singleton is an instantiation policy, defined in your code

So the answer to your question is "it depends on how you've implemented the instantiation policy".

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand right, what you want to achieve is a reusable singleton pattern base class. You can do this using a template base class, using a pattern named [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) also provides a simple explanation of this technique.

Concretely, it would mean doing something like this:

```
template<typename TDerived>
class Singleton {
public:
    static TDerived& instance() {
         static TDerived instance_;
         return instance_;
    }
protected:
    Singleton() {}
    virtual ~Singleton() {}
};

class ConcreteSingleton : public Singleton<ConcreteSingleton> {
public:
    ...
protected:
    ConcreteSingleton() {
         ...
    }
    virtual ~ConcreteSingleton() {
         ...
    }

};
```

This particular version requires that your base classes have a default constructor. Other, more complex interfaces can alleviate that issue.

Overall, as pointed out in some comments, singleton as a pattern has scalability issues, though const singletons are generally considered safer.